# Conversion operator is slicing my object

Tags: c++, object-slicing, conversion-operator

I'm getting unexpected behavior from the following code:

```
struct Base
{
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}

    virtual void foo() const = 0;

protected:
    Base(const Base &) {}
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    Derived() {}
    Derived(const Derived &other) : Base(other) {}

    virtual void foo() const {}
};

struct NewDerived
{
    operator const Derived() { return Derived(); }
};

void func(const Base &b)
{
    b.foo();
}

int main()
{
    func(NewDerived());
    return 0;
}
```

With MSVC2008, I get this compilation error in main():

```
error C2248: 'Base::Base' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'Base'
```

Why is it trying to access the copy constructor of Base?

If I make Base's copy constructor public, the code compiles and slices the return value at runtime and the call to foo() inside func() triggers a pure virtual function called error.

Can someone please shed a bit of light?

Answer (score 6):

The relevant quote from the standard is in 8.5.3p5 (C++11):

> has a class type (i.e., T2 is a class type), where T1 is not
>   reference-related to T2, and can be implicitly converted to an xvalue,
>   class prvalue, or function lvalue of type “cv3 T3”, where “cv1 T1” is
>   reference-compatible with “cv3 T3”, then the reference is bound to the
>   value of the initializer expression in the first case and to the
>   **result of the conversion in the second case (or, in either case, to an
>   appropriate base class subobject**).
>
> Example:

```
struct A { };
struct B : A { } b;
extern B f();
const A& rca2 = f(); // bound to the A subobject of the B rvalue.
A&& rra = f(); // same as above
struct X {
operator B();
operator int&();
} x;
const A& r = x; // bound to the A subobject of the result of the conversion
```

In your case, `T1` is `Base`, `T2` is `NewDerived`, and `T3` is `Derived`. From the above quote, the copy constructor **should not** be called and the lvalue reference should bind to the `Base` subobject.

However, note that in C++03, this was not the case. In C++03, the following quotes were pertinent:

> If the initializer expression is an rvalue, with T2 a class type, and
>   “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2,” the reference is bound
>   to the object represented by the rvalue (see 3.10 [basic.lval]) or to
>   a sub-object within that object.

...

> Otherwise, **a temporary of type “cv1 T1” is created** and initialized
>   from the initializer expression using the rules for a non-reference
>   copy initialization (8.5 [dcl.init]). The reference is then bound to
>   the temporary.

The first quoted paragraph does not apply, because `Base` is not reference compatible with `NewDerived`, so only the last paragraph applies, which means a temporary `Base` object must be created. Therefore, MSVC2008 and gcc are conforming to C++03 rules.

Comment: As a side note, why does the following minor change to the code allows it to compile, at least in VS:

`int main()
{
   const Base& b(NewDerived());
}`

Any ideas ??

Comment: @AlexK:You've been struck by [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Try `const Base& b((NewDerived()));` (Note the extra parentheses).

Comment: @Jesse Got it. Great catch !

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys. That's helpful.  I added a Bonus Question if you have any creative ideas.

Comment: @kede: It's hard to say with just a small snippet of code. I couldn't see why the conversion function is not returning a `File`? Perhaps a separate question with the full code woud help.

Comment: Good point. I removed it. I may ask it as a separate question later.